# Why am I getting getApplicationcontext() null?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, android-intentservice

I'm not sure whats wrong in it! I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8349306/2284107) that Intentservice is itself a subclass of `Context`.

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    Context mainContext;
    WriteFile writeFile;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
        mainContext = getApplicationContext();
        writeFile = new WriteFile(mainContext);
    }
    // My rest of the code
}
```

but I'm getting null value for `mainContext`.
Any suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the constructor it is way too early to access the app context. Try to move this code into the `onCreate` method.

More datails about the life cycle can be found in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle)

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling this in your onCreate method, not the constructor.  In the constructor, the application context has not been set up yet, so it will be null.

Answer (score 2):

To get application context in a good way, you should use in following way.

Use following way

**Step 1**

Create an Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

**Step 2**

In Android Manifest file declare following

```
<application android:name="com.xyz.MyApplication">
   ...
</application>
```

**Step 3**

Use following method to call Application context anywhere in your application.

```
MyApplication.getAppContext();
```

Like,

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    Context mainContext;
    WriteFile writeFile;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
        mainContext = MyApplication.getAppContext();
        writeFile = new WriteFile(mainContext);
    }
    // My rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GCMNotificationIntentService.this` or simply `this` instead of `mainContext`.

`IntentService` extends `Service` which is itself a subclass of `Context`